# how to override Ctrl+V in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, overriding, keypress

I need to cleanup the HTML of pasted text into TinyMCE by passing it to a webservice and then getting it back into the textarea.
So I need to override the Ctrl+V in TinyMCE to caputre the text, do a background request, and on return continue with whatever the paste handler was for TinyMCE.
First off, where is TinyMCE's Ctrl+V handler, and is there a non-destructive way to override it? (instead of changing the source code)

Answer (score 3):

You could write a plug-in that handles the ctrl+v event and passes it through or modify the paste plug-in. The following code is found at [plugins/paste/editor_plugin.js](http://source.ibiblio.org/trac/lyceum/browser/vendor/wordpress/trunk/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/editor_plugin.js?rev=1241) and it handles the ctrl+v event.

```
  handleEvent : function(e) {
          // Force paste dialog if non IE browser
          if (!tinyMCE.isRealIE && tinyMCE.getParam("paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste", false) && e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 86 && e.type == "keydown") {
             window.setTimeout('tinyMCE.selectedInstance.execCommand("mcePasteText",true)', 1);
             return tinyMCE.cancelEvent(e);
          }

          return true;
       },
```

Here is some [more information about creating plug-ins for tinyMCE](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Creating_Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Tiny Editor has a plugin called "paste".

When using it, you can define two functions in the init-section

```
/**
 * This option enables you to modify the pasted content BEFORE it gets
 * inserted into the editor.
 */
paste_preprocess : function(plugin, args)
{
     //Replace empty styles
    args.content = args.content.replace(/<style><\/style>/gi, "");
}
```

and

```
/**
 * This option enables you to modify the pasted content before it gets inserted
 * into the editor ,but after it's been parsed into a DOM structure.
 *
 * @param plugin
 * @param args
 */
paste_postprocess : function(plugin, args) {
    var paste_content= args.node.innerHTML;
    console.log('Node:');
    console.log(args.node);

}
```